# Stop Git from Opening a new Terminal.app Window on Commit

Tags: mac, terminal, git, version-control, iterm

Git is automatically opening a Terminal window when I save commit messages on my Mac. This might normally be useful (e.g. if the commit was initiated from a Terminal window), but I use iTerm as my terminal emulator and as such this is just annoying. Is there anyway to configure Git to either use iTerm or otherwise stop doing this altogether?

Comment: Nothing like this has ever happened to me. Mind showing us your `git config -l`?

Comment: Also show us your environment (`env`) so we can see what the editor-related variables are. Also, are you using some Git GUI interface, or the command line git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A-ha! So running `env` and re-examining my environment variables, I came across this little gem:

```
EDITOR=mvim -f -c "au VimLeave * !open -a Terminal"
```

I had apparently set my editor (MacVim in this case) to automatically reopen my terminal window when I was done, long before I was using iTerm.app. Changing this to a simple

```
EDITOR=mvim -f -c "au VimLeave * !open -a iTerm"
```

alleviated my problem. Thanks for your answers and for providing me with the spark I needed to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you system is trying to open a terminal window so you can enter the commit message?  If so, you can make your commits without an editor like this:

```
git commit -m"My commit message here"
```

If you just type:

```
git commit
```

Then git opens an editor window so that you can provide the commit message.  Hope this helps.